# What is the policy on commercial users?

Tags: discussion, spam, user-accounts

I've seen a few questions just pop up from [this account](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/23036/velosurance).  It seems like the answers that are posted are actually relevant and typed by a human, but it's obviously an account that belongs to a corporate entity rather than belonging to an individual. The name and logo are of that corporate entity.  Some of the answers, such as [this one](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/35055/163) actually link back to their site.

Are these posts within the acceptable use policy for this site?  While some of the information is useful, it seems like they are using the site more as an advertising source to get people to find out about their product. It seems like they have an ulterior motive for answering questions that already have sufficient answers simply to get their name on more pages.

Comment: Looks like so far one out of six answers doesn't link to their website, and at least one is a copy'n'paste from their website. I say they're spamming.

Comment: Can we also cover @Criggie's "how can we help them be useful" in answers, as I think that's important. If the person is trying to add useful answers we should help them rather than just assume they're trying for minimum-effort embedding of advertising links. I'm tempted to edit out their links and see if they're still happy to have their answers up.

Answer (score 4):

I'd refer to the last part of [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  If they want to post good answers or questions, fine.  Good answers or questions with self promotion should also contain disclosure about the business.  Duplicate spam answers or questions should be flagged/downvoted and deleted.  We may also choose to delete any answers or questions that do not have that disclosure from this particular account since disclosure is listed as a *must*.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no disclosure *ever* from that account. It's just implicit in the user name = business name.